# ReferenceError: timer is not defined > clearTimeout(timer);

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I'm trying to use the price filter in magento, but I'm getting the error:

ReferenceError: timer is not defined > clearTimeout(timer);

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            mgsjQuery(function($) {
                var newMinPrice, newMaxPrice, url, temp;
                var categoryMinPrice = 0;
                var categoryMaxPrice = 74.9000;
                function isNumber(n) {
                  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) &amp;&amp; isFinite(n);
                }

                $(".priceTextBox").focus(function(){
                    temp = $(this).val();   
                });

                $(".priceTextBox").keyup(function(){
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    if(!isNumber(value)){
                        $(this).val(temp);  
                    }
                });

                $(".priceTextBox").keypress(function(e){
                    if(e.keyCode == 13){
                        var value = $(this).val();
                        if(value &lt; categoryMinPrice || value &gt; categoryMaxPrice){
                            $(this).val(temp);  
                        }
                        url = getUrl($("#minPrice").val(), $("#maxPrice").val());
                        sliderAjax(url);    
                    }   
                });

                $(".priceTextBox").blur(function(){
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    if(value &lt; categoryMinPrice || value &gt; categoryMaxPrice){
                        $(this).val(temp);  
                    }

                });

                $(".go").click(function(){
                    url = getUrl($("#minPrice").val(), $("#maxPrice").val());
                    sliderAjax(url);    
                });

                $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
                    range: true,
                    min: categoryMinPrice,
                    max: categoryMaxPrice,
                    values: [ 6.8000, 74.9000 ],
                    slide: function( event, ui ) {
                        newMinPrice = ui.values[0];
                        newMaxPrice = ui.values[1];

                        $( "#amount" ).val( "R$ " + newMinPrice + " - R$ " + newMaxPrice );



                    },stop: function( event, ui ) {

                        // Current Min and Max Price
                        var newMinPrice = ui.values[0];
                        var newMaxPrice = ui.values[1];

                        // Update Text Price
                        $( "#amount" ).val( "R$ "+newMinPrice+" - R$ "+newMaxPrice );



                        url = getUrl(newMinPrice,newMaxPrice);
                        if(newMinPrice != 6.8000 &amp;&amp; newMaxPrice != 74.9000){
                            clearTimeout(timer); // << Line with error
                            //window.location= url;

                        }else{
                                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                                    sliderAjax(url);
                                }, 0);     
                            }
                    }
                });

                function getUrl(newMinPrice, newMaxPrice){
                    return "https://www.webshop.com/deals/"+"?min="+newMinPrice+"&amp;max="+newMaxPrice+"&amp;ModPagespeed=off";
                }
            });
        </script>
```

For better understanding, i put a note "Line with error" in the code. * The errors line was Indicated by Firebug.

Comment: I'd suggest `if (timer) { clearTimeout(timer); }`.  Or assigning `timer` before your `if` statement instead of inside of the `else` clause.

Comment: `timer` define globally you will not get this error.

Comment: @aroth I made the change but still the error. if (timer) { clearTimeout(timer); } do you have other suggestions?